# Is it possible to set docker port mappings to host in Dockerfile?

Tags: networking, docker, vagrant, dockerfile

I'm using a multi-machine Vagrant setup, and one of the VMs is a docker host that runs some containers built with custom Dockerfiles.

Each one of the container is different, and exposes some ports to the host. Can I force a port mapping directly in the Dockerfile, instead of having to set the mapping with the `docker run -p` command?

For example, in the Dockerfile I have:

```
EXPOSE 8080
```

If I run the container with `docker run -P`, docker publishes the 8080 port on a random port in the host (which is useless in my specific case). Can I force docker to publish the X port on a specified Y port on the host, without having to run custom `docker run -p Y:X` commands?

Comment: Your deployment script can just inspect the image for ports and pass the necessary -p option to the run command.

Comment: @IgorBukanov: But I'm using the Docker provisioner in Vagrant, that has a direct "docker run" method. Adding a deploy script that performs the needed operations nullifies the convenience of Vagrant.

Answer (score 1):

`docker run --net=host ...` *might* solve your problem, but generally it is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

It's not useless it's by design. You can run a container multiple times simultaneously. If the mapping was part of the dockerfile you would a) have no control on how to manage this port across fleets (load balancers) b) have conflicts on multiple instance trying to bind to the same host port and c) a bunch of other issues.

The answer is no.

Comment: I meant "useless" in my specific case. Obviously random ports are useful in other situations. The problem, in my Vagrant/Docker deploy, is that I can't know a priori on what ports the container will be bound, and I can't have a Vagrantfile with the network already set up.